# Laravel - Is it possible to save data to a mySQL database from a external website?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, guzzle

Lets say I found a website that has the following markup:

```html
<body>
  <div id="paper">
    <div id="contentwrapper">
      <div id="rightcontent">
        <h1>1967-002A</h1>
        <p>
          <strong>NSSDCA/COSPAR ID:</strong> 1967-002A</p>
        <div class="twocol">
          <div class="urone">
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <p>
              This US Air Force photo surveillance satellite was launched from Vandenberg AFB aboard a Thor Agena D rocket. It was a KH-4A (Key Hole-4A) type satellite. The satellite had fair image quality.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="urtwo">
            <h2>Alternate Names</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>02642</li>
            </ul>
            <h2>Facts in Brief</h2>
            <p>
              <strong>Launch Date:</strong> 1967-01-14
              <br/>
              <strong>Launch Vehicle:</strong> Thor
              <br/>
              <strong>Launch Site:</strong> Vandenberg AFB, United States
              <br/>
              <strong>Mass:</strong> 1500.0 kg
              <br/>
            </p>
            <h2>Funding Agency</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Department of Defense-Department of the Air Force (United States)</li>
            </ul>
            <h2>Discipline</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Surveillance and Other Military</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This contains information, such as Description, Launch Date, Launch Vehicle, Launch Site and Mass, Funding Agency and Discipline. - These could all be the columns in the mySQL database.

The webpage has a link of `/spacecraftDisplay.do?id=1967-002A`. I already have a database with the `1967-002A` - the spacecraft identifier. So I am guessing to take each identifier from my database and save the data from the URL with the same identifier. Each webpage is the same

I already know how to save data from an external API which has a JSON format using Guzzle. Instead of JSON, we are dealing with the HTML of the external website.

What I want to know first, if its possible to even save this data from the webpage or is there limitations to what you can do?

Comment: I had the similar issue I used selenium to read the HTML and get the values out of it.

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "DOM parser".  You can use it to parse information from structured HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with a DOM parser http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

It basically sticks an entire HTML page in an object then you can access any element from that object.

```
//Example
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    echo $element->src . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Just tried your example and it results in a `file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking` error. I have included the class.

Comment: Perfect! It worked. I will see if I can save the data in the database and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I am able to get the description with no problem. One thing - Is there any way to only get the Launch Vehicle and Discipline (as shown in HTML file in question)?